# No Multitouch using ScatterView, MultitouchVista and Surface SDK

Tags: c#, wpf, multi-touch, pixelsense, scatterview

I have installed Microsoft Surface SDK 1.0 SP1 on Win7 with 64bit following this instructions: 
www.brianpeek.com/blog/archive/2009/05/14/install-the-surface-sdk-sp1-workstation-edition-on-x64.aspx

No problems so far. To test my application I use MultitouchVista (see here: multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) with two mice. (**update:** I tried with Surface Simulator and it worked, so it might not be a code issue)

If I want to try out the example ScatterPuzzle (is included in SurfaceSDK) only one point is used. So i can not scale or rotate, or even move two objects at the same time.

even this simple example from msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee957318.aspx does not work:

```
<s:SurfaceWindow 
x:Class="ScatterViewOverview.SurfaceWindow1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.microsoft.com/surface/2008"
Title="ScatterViewOverview">

<s:ScatterView>
    <Image Source="Resources/Desert.jpg"/>
</s:ScatterView>

</s:SurfaceWindow>
```

Is that some kind of a known bug or am I doing somethingh wrong?

Thanks.

PS: For example in the current approach I use RotateTransform to rotate and ManipulationDelta to calculate the needed rotation degree of my Item.

***Edit:***
Yes, I tried it with the Surface Simulator, and it works great. The problem is, that I need to use MultiTouchVista. We built a Multitouch-Table that gets the same input as simulated with the mice.

I found a Video on Youtube where MultiTouchVista is used on the Demo Applications: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHsqS2QnR14 
He seems to had it working.

***Edit2:***
It seems, that the items of the SDK need ContactEvents, but MultitouchVista "only" gives you TouchEvents. So they won't work without heavy workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're developing a Surface application, you shouldn't need multitouchvista. That might be causing the issue. You need to run the application inside the surface simulator, which uses the mouse to emulate surface contacts. Multiple mice will work independently within the simulator to allow for multitouch interactions.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use MultiTouchVista. And I want to have the features of the SDK... we'll see.

Comment: I tried and tried and tried... It seems, that the items of the SDK need ContactEvents, but MultitouchVista "only" gives you TouchEvents. So they won't work without heavy workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Surface Toolkit? It is a collection of surface controls. They work in Windows Applications and toolkit has almost the same set of sample applications.

Anyway you can try to use

```
<s:ScatterView>
    <s:ScatterViewItem Width="500" Height="500" />
</s:ScatterView>
```

And if it works - wrap controls into this items.